# Spring cache not working

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache

I am trying to use Spring Cache with Ehcache . The problem is when my app startsup its not showing any exception but it makes my app to shutdown.

The following is the code snippet.

```
  @Cacheable(value="offerInformation",key="#offerInformation.accountType.value.concat('-').concat(#offerInformation.externalId).concat('-').concat(#offerInformation.accountTypeId)")
    public OfferInformation findOfferInformation(OfferInformation offerInformation){
        // We make sure the item will be returned from cache

        return null;
}
```

The following is the logs generating when i am strating my app

```
    2013-08-21 09:05:39,507 DEBUG [main]  Adding cacheable method 'findOfferInformation' with attribute: [CacheableOperation[public com.ericsson.enk.ene.model.OfferInformation com.ericsson.enk.ene.cache.AddOfferInfoToCache.findOfferInformation(com.ericsson.enk.ene.model.OfferInformation)] caches=[offerInformation] | condition='' | key='#offerInformation.accountType.value.concat('-').concat(#offerInformation.externalId).concat('-').concat(#offerInformation.accountTypeId)']
2013-08-21 09:05:39,507 DEBUG [main]  Creating implicit proxy for bean 'addOfferInfoToCache' with 0 common interceptors and 1 specific interceptors
2013-08-21 09:05:39,508 INFO  [main]  Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6a969c29: defining beans
```

I am using Spring 3.1.1 version. Please help me.

Comment: What does your program loonks like? Do you start any thread? a GUI? What does the main method do except loading a Spring application context? Show us the code.

Comment: I don't really know reason of your error, but I can suggest your not use `concat('-')` in key, just use SpEl declaration of array '{#offerInformation.accountType.value, #offerInformation.externalId, #offerInformation.accountTypeId}'

Comment: I really doubt if this is a spring cache implementation problem.
2013-08-21 09:05:39,508 INFO  [main]  Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6a969c29: defining beans
This line suggests me that there is some problem initializing the spring context.
Also  please try upgrading spring version to 4.1.* onwards, as spring cache explicitly specifies

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?129579-How-to-construct-a-key-for-cache-in-Cacheable-annotation

From last comment in above post it seems you need to change key:

> Spring can't call the returned object's method from the proxy it generated. It's trying to access the returned object in the cached method, rather than accessing the method in the class

Try changing key as below:

```
@Cacheable(value = "offerInformation",
           key = "#offerInformation.accountType+'-'+#offerInformation.externalId+'-'+#offerInformation.accountTypeId")
public OfferInformation findOfferInformation(OfferInformation offerInformation) {
        // make sure the item will be returned from cache
        return null;
}
```